# Given a finitely generated, residually finite, non-cohopfian group $G$, can the following abelianizations ALL be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated, residually finite, non-cohopfian group. Since $G$ is residually finite, we know that there exists a sequence of nested, normal, finite index subgroups $$G  = N_0 \rhd  N_1  \rhd N_2    \ldots $$ with the trivial intersection.

**Question**: Is it possible that all $N_i$ have finite abelianization, *i.e.* the quotient group $N_i \big/ [N_i,N_i]$ is finite for every $i$?

**My thoughts so far**: It is clear that $G$ can't be finite (finite implies cohopfian) or abelian or free (free groups have infinite abelianization). The closest group I was informed is $D_{\infty} = \; \left<r,s \;|\; srs=r^{-1}, s^2=1 \right>$, which is finitely generated, residually finite and non-cohopfian. However, for any sequence of nested, normal, finite index subgroups with the trivial intersection  $D_{\infty} = N_0 \rhd  N_1  \rhd N_2    \ldots $, we eventually have $N_i$ contains only rotations, which means $N_i$ is infinite abelian, hence has infinite abelianization.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [Grigorchuk group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group) has all of these properties.

It is finitely generated, residually finite and non-cohopfian. Since it is a torsion group and the $N_i$ are all finitely generated, they must have finite abelianization.

Comment: Thank you!! I was thinking of the Grigorchuk group, too, but didn't realise we can show all $N_i$ have finite abelianization in this way.